# ASPNet Core - the call is ambiguous in Startup.cs configure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**asp.net core 
.net 461**

A dependency in my project.json is causing ambiguity errors, I'm having trouble locating it. Any help is appreciated!

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327196/asp-net-mvc-core-the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properti), but it's not as obvious (to me) where the problem lies.

**Startup.cs**
[image]

**project.json**

```
"dependencies": {
 "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta1",
"log4net": "2.0.8",
"MailKit": "1.16.0",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "1.0.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.2",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
"MimeKit": "1.16.0",
  },
```

[image]

Comment: Try to update `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.*` packages. Then, as usual, try to close VS, delete `.vs` folder, run `dotnet restore` from CMD.

Comment: I would start by upgrading to asp.net core 1.1.x if possible as there were some pretty major changes and improvements. That may or may not solve your specific problem but it will probably make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: Look at your dependency graph in VS Project view (open every tree of Dependencies "folder" until you find the dependency which uses an very outdated ASP.NET Core version)

Comment: removing Glimpse, running dotnet restore and restarting vs seemed to help. Thanks for the advice guys - @Ilya if you make your comment the answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.*` packages. Then, as usual:

- Close Visual Studio.
- Delete `.vs` folder.
- Run `dotnet restore` from CMD.