# Ambiguity between 'Startup.Configuration' and 'Startup.Configuration'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get an error of "Ambiguity between 'Startup.Configuration' and 'Startup.Configuration'" on my startup class. I don't know what I have done to cause this issue. All I did was create a DBContext class and this error occured. Please see my code below:

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using IssueTracker.Data;

namespace IssueTracker
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            // Enabling CORS
            services.AddCors(options => 
            {
                options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder => 
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().Build();
                });
            });

            // Connect to the Database
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.getConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
using IssueTracker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace IssueTracker.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) {}

        // Creating the roles
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
                new { Id = "1", name="Admin", NoralizeName = "ADMIN" },
                new { Id = "1", name="Customer", NoralizeName = "CUSTOMER" },
                new { Id = "1", name="Moderator", NoralizeName = "MODERATOR" }
            );
        }

        public DbSet<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924513/aspnet-core-the-call-is-ambiguous-in-startup-cs-configure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327196/asp-net-mvc-core-the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properti)?

Comment: I have seen that post already. I didn't think it was the same issue. Anyways, thank you. I think that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and simply closing and reopening my IDE (Visual Studio Code) solved it. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this error might be that you have accidently made a copy of `Startup.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

I coppied solution file for backup purposes then I got that error. When I delete the backup file problem solved.