# Scaffolding not working in Visual Studio 2022 .NET 6 Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, asp.net-core-6.0

I could not get the reflection type for this LoginViewModel:

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Scaffolding forced me to choose the context, but "LoginViewModel" is not listed in contexts:

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

**How do I solve this?**

Comment: Do you mean you have a different Dbcontext for LoginViewModel but you are not able to select it? What happens if you try to click the Add button(+ icon)? Are you able to see your Dbcontext? Could you please inform us how you have created the Dbcontext?

Comment: Loginviewmodel is just a model created to scaffold to create strongly type view but the wizard force me to choose context (I need to scaffold without using context)

Comment: I understand that you need to select the Context file but you want to scaffold without it. I would suggest try to create empty context file or context file with the dummy values that you could select while scaffold. See whether it work that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by a mismatch of versions. Check your Nuget packages. Refer to this question: [asp.net mvc core The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327196/asp-net-mvc-core-the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properti)

Comment: all packages with the same version but still not working